# Updating widget with TimelineProvider when phone is off/disconnected?

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

So, if I set entries in TimelineProvider to update the widget every midnight and the data depends on a network call, what happens if the user turns off the phone or puts it in airplane mode? Will it be placed in some kind of queue so that it will try to run the network call once the phone is turned on or gets an internet connection? If not, what would be the best approach to keep the widget up-to-date?

Maybe creating timeline entries for every hour and canceling all the entries for the current day once the data has been fetched, then rescheduling the entries for the following day?

Also, what will happen if the user has the phone turned off for like a week? Will the widget call the `getTimeline()` method to update the timeline when the phone starts up?

Additionally, is there a best practice to visually indicate that a widget doesn't show up-to-date information?

Comment: All of this depends on how your getTimeline is setup. Apple does very little for you, you should account for failed calls and inform the user accordingly